# Trying to create a config with typescript for node

Tags: node.js, typescript

So I try to be a good boy and do things right, and currently I thought I would write a rather simple application to update database tables, and as the tables belong to an application, and have to be spot on, but very fiddly, I thought I would write it all in typescript.

I wen't through part of the Typescript course on edx.org, seemed easy enough, but I have an issue translating a simple config export to a class.

Basically, I am trying to replace a simple config object (would have looked like this in Javascript).

./config/config.js

```
modules.exports = {
    'lokiLogDb': "./database/log.db",
    'lokiCfgDb': "./database/cfg.db"
}
```

I would call it like 
var config = require('./config/config');

So my new ./config/config.ts

```
export class config {
    private _lokiLogDb : string = "./database/log.db";
    private _lokiCfgDb : string = "./database/cfg.db";
    private _lokiCfgKey : string = "Th1sC0uldUnl0ckYourK3y";
    get lokiLogDb () {
        return this._lokiLogDb;
    }
    get lokiCfgDb () {
        return this._lokiCfgDb;
    }
    set lokiCfgKey (passwd: string ) {
        return "Not ready yet";
    }
    get lokiCfgKey () {
        return "Not ready yet"
    }
}
```

OK, maybe a bit over the top, but worth testing I thought.
So next step is to import the values:
import * as config from './config/config';

And that is where it all falls to pieces. I can not read any values from my module. What am I doing wrong, or what have I missed?

======= UPDATE =======

So my updated config.ts

```
export default class config {
    private _lokiLogDb : string = "./database/log.db";
    private _lokiCfgDb : string = "./database/cfg.db";
    private _lokiCfgKey : string = "secretcode";

    get lokiLogDb () {
        return this._lokiLogDb;
    }
    get lokiCfgDb () {
        return this._lokiCfgDb;
    }
    set lokiCfgKey (passwd: string ) {
        return "Not ready yet";
    }
    get lokiCfgKey () {
        return "Not ready yet"
    }
}
```

And the beginning of my app.ts

```
import * as debugFactory from 'debug';
import * as http from 'http';
import * as express from 'express';
import * as path from 'path';
import * as logger from 'morgan';
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';

import config from './config/config';
console.log("Will connect to ", config )
//import localDB from './modules/localdb';

import sampleRoute from './routes/sample';
```

And the output I get is

```
Will connect to  function config() {
        this._lokiLogDb = "./database/log.db";
        this._lokiCfgDb = "./database/cfg.db";
        this._lokiCfgKey = "secret";
    }
```

But I cant get to any of the variables, am I just doing this in a silly way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

`export default class config` in your `config.ts`

and import it with:

`import {config} from './config/config'`.

Also, make sure you are really transpiling your typescript to javascript.

Comment: I am clearly missing something, updated my own code above (well will have in one minute)